# Retrieving data from MySQL and displaying the result as options in a search box using JSP

Tags: java, ajax

I wanted to make the `search-box` to `select` the options which are retrieved from MySQL by the user dynamically.

I have tried to `retrieve` the data from MySQL and made it available in the `search-box`.

## AJAX Function

```js
<script>
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
function searchStudent() {
    var s_Name = document.vinform.s_Name.value;
    var url = 'Student.jsp?val=' + s_Name;

    try {
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState == 4) {
                var val = request.responseText;
                document.getElementById('mylocation2').innerHTML = val;
            }
        }; //end of function  
        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send();
    } catch (e) {
        alert('Unable to connect to server');
    }
}
</script>
```

## JSP Page

```jsp
<label class="col-sm-3 text-right control-label col-form-label">Search:</label>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <input type="search" name="s_Name" onkeyup="searchStudent()" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Candidate" autofocus="autofocus">
    <span id="mylocation2" style="height: 10px; width: 20%;"></span>
</div>
```

## Student.jsp

```jsp
<%
    String s_Name = request.getParameter("val");
    if (s_Name == null || s_Name.trim().equals("")) {
        out.print("<p style=\"color: red;\">Please enter Student name!</p>");
    } else {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/geniustechnology", "root", "");
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM enquiry_master WHERE enquiry_name LIKE '" + s_Name + "%'");
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if (!rs.isBeforeFirst()) {
                out.println("<p style=\"color: red;\">No Record Found!</p>");
            } else {
                out.print("<table frame=\"box\" width=\"1024\" style=\"height: 36px; width: 100%;\">");
                while (rs.next()) {
                    //out.println("<div style=\"width:500px; border-style: solid; border-color: red;\"><table border=\"1\" style=\"margin-left: 180px; margin-top: 5px; width:auto;\">");
                    out.print("<tr><td>" + rs.getString(2) + "</td></tr>");  
                }  
                out.print("</table>");
            } // end of else for rs.isBeforeFirst   
        con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        out.print(e);
    }
%>
```

As shown in the `screenshot` below, i am able to see the `database` came from database but `not` able to `select` it.

[image]

Comment: then what is your problem ? BTW, the code looks like from last century

Comment: What are you not able to do,does it give you any error?

Comment: I am not able to select the searched option.

Comment: What output did you get , when you searched something ..?

Comment: i am able to get database records in the search box through span tag but span tag doesn't allows to select the options available in the search-box.